# Simplify equation with limits in the infinity

Tags: integration, limits

I'm studying the book from Prof. Stewart[Cauculus : early transcendentals 7th Ed. p. 376]. In the chapter about integration I've found the following equation:
[image: lim]

My questions are:

1) why he changed the **n** for the power that is in **n**? For instance, notice the **54/n^2** turning **27**.

2) what are the steps to simplify  **n(n+1)/2** into **1 + 1/n**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: He's simplyfying.. $54/2=27$ and $n(n+1)/n^2=(n+1)/n$

Comment: And similarly, he expanded the square and got $81/4$ multiplied by $n^2(n+1)^2$. And notice that $(n+1)/n=1+1/n$

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I didn't get. Sam's answer below just made it cristal clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Biggr\{\frac {81}{n^4}\Biggr[\frac {n(n+1)}2\Biggr]^2-\frac{54}{n^2}\frac {n(n+1)}2\Biggr\}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Biggr\{\frac {81}{n^4}\Biggr[\frac {n^2+n}2\Biggr]^2-\frac{54}{n^2}\frac {(n^2+n)}2\Biggr\}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Biggr\{\frac {81}{(n^2)^2}\Biggr[\frac {(n^2+n)^2}4\Biggr]-\frac{54}2\Biggr(\frac {n^2+n}{n^2}\Biggr)\Biggr\}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Biggr\{\frac {81}4\Biggr(\frac {n^2+n}{n^2}\Biggr)^2-\frac{54}2\Biggr(\frac {n^2+n}{n^2}\Biggr)\Biggr\}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Biggr\{\frac {81}4\Biggr(1+\frac 1n\Biggr)^2-27\Biggr(1+\frac 1n\Biggr)\Biggr\}\end{align}$$

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you very much.